# gcc inline assembly function that clobbers all the floating-point registers

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to write an `asm` statement (inline assembly in **GCC**), that just calls some function, that returns one value in floating-point register and has no operands, but potentially clobbers all the floating-point registers.

```
asm("call *%1"
    : "=t"(result_)
    : "d"(code_.data())
    : "memory", "cc", "ax", "%st(1)", "%st(2)", "%st(3)", "%st(4)", "%st(5)", "%st(6)", "%st(7)"
    );
```

My problem is that I cannot tell the assembler, that is clobbering the top floating-point register `%st(0)` too, because I cannot specify `"%st(0)"` (or `"%st"`) in clobber list (it results in an compilation error).

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a result in `%st(0)`; that is what the `t` constraint means. The compiler therefore knows it is modified.

I am not sure why your GCC is not recognizing `%st(0)` or `%st` as a name in the clobber list, but this should not cause a problem in this situation.

Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60) accepts `%st` in the clobber list, even with `=t` as an output constraint.

Comment: `error: unknown register name '%st(0)' in 'asm'` or `error: 'asm' operand has impossible constraints` in case of `"st"` or `error: unknown register name '%st()' in 'asm'` in case of `"st()"`

Comment: g++ --version: `g++.exe (rev1, Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.8.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...`

Comment: The correct register for clobbering is `st`.  The error message you are seeing here comes from the fact that you are both clobbering it AND returning it (`=t` means return the value in `st`).  You can do either (or neither), but you can't both clobber it and return it.  That's an `impossible constraint.`